# Is there a way, given a MySQL transaction id, to see a log of the queries that have been run it?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL transaction id, and  a lovely MySQL console. Is there a way, from this, to get a list of the queries that have been run in that transaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming by "transaction id" you mean "thread id".

This is only possible if you enable the general query log. That logs every query run on the server. It adds enough overhead that most people do not use it in production. However if you do happen to use `general_log = 'ON'` and `log_output = 'TABLE'` in your environment then you can look at the query history for a given thread id like this:

```
select * 
from mysql.general_log
where thread_id = <your_thread_id>
order by event_time desc
```

The ids eventually roll over, so you should probably limit your query to an appropriate time wondow (the past hour, past day, etc.) For example to limit it to the past day:

```
select * 
from mysql.general_log
where thread_id = <your_thread_id>
and event_time >= now() - interval 1 day
order by event_time desc
```